# Java.util auto correcting invalid date

Tags: date, auto, java.util.date, xmlgregoriancalendar

Java.util.date package is auto correcting date. For ex: if we pass date as "2018-02-35", it automatically changes it to "2018-03-07", which is a valid date.

Basically, the requirement is to validate the user entered date but as the date is getting auto corrected the module was never able to find an incorrect date. (Note: UI validation can't be done due to some special restrictions so the validation has to be done by the middleware system).

Is there a way i can handle this with the same util package or can this be handled through any 3rd party jar? pls advise

Comment: A rest service cannot receive a XMLGregorianCalendar object. Do you mean you are receiving text that you are parsing as an XMLGregorianCalendar object? If so exactly what text are you getting? Just the month and day shown here? Your Question is poorly written and unclear. I suggest you rewrite for clarity. As currently written I must vote to close as unclear.

Comment: It is a jaxb object that is generated out of a xsd, the field is defined as date in xsd schema so the jaxb class has created an xmlgregoriancalendar object. Value is passed as "yyyy-MM-yyThh:mm:ss.sss". when i try to read the input by calling appropriate "getter" bean, the value gets automatically changed and that is the issue. hope i made it clear this time

Comment: Post further details as edits to your Question, not as comments.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I admit that from your question even after your edit I don’t have a very clear picture of what’s going on. I think that if you [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we’ll be able to help you out. Which we’d love to do.

Comment: Are you aware how outdated and poorly designed the `java.util.Date` class is? You should prefer to use `java.time.LocalDate` for a date without time of day.

Answer (score 0):

Even i faced same issue. But after some research i found that there is method (setLenient()) in the DateFormat class to disable this behaviour.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
df.setLenient(false);
```

Java Docs: 
Specify whether or not date/time parsing is to be lenient. With lenient parsing, the parser may use heuristics to interpret inputs that do not precisely match this object's format. With strict parsing, inputs must match this object's format.

Comment: Thanks Neeraj but this value is read from a rest service call (Json value) so the input gets auto corrected before mapping to an input VO so it doesn’t let me apply any formatting

Comment: Even I'm also reading the value from rest call (json value). For this to work you can write DateDeserializer and annotate your date property in the media class with that DateDeserializer. See the code snippet in another comment

Comment: I fixed the issue by using @jsonformat annotation(has to be version 2.9 and above) by setting lenient property to false

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 0):

you can write DateDeserializer

```
public class DateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date> {
    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", getLocale());
        format.setLenient(false); // if true, will auto correct the date  
                                  // to the next possible valid date
        String date = jp.getText();
        try {
            return format.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private Locale getLocale() {
        Locale locale = (LocaleContextHolder.getLocale() != null) ? LocaleContextHolder.getLocale() : Locale.getDefault();
        return locale;
    }

}
```

And then annotate your date property in the media class with this DateDeserializer. You can also use dateSerializer to serialize the object back to Json format. Example below

```
@JsonSerialize(using=DateSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using=DateDeserializer.class)
private Date startDate;
```

Comment: Rather than supplying new answers you may edit your old answer. You have got [an edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51394589/edit) under it.